# 2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget year validation

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using 2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget.After selecting the date, user can edit the year which can be invalid like 10/30/0233. (m/d/Y)

I want to restrict user to enter invalid year, or to allow the date between specific year range only. without making the datefield readonly. How can I achieve this.

```
       echo $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
                                    'addon' => '<i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                    'class' => 'form-control',
                                    'clientOptions' => [
                                        'autoclose' => true,
                                        'format' => Yii::$app->params['dateFormat'],
                                    ],

                                ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it using custom validator as follows

add rule for date  as follows

```
    ['my_date', 'validYear'], // custom validator to check year range
```

Then define custom rule as follows

```
public function validYear($attribute, $params) {

        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $this->my_date);
        $year = $date->format("Y");
        $year_range = range(date('Y'), date('Y')+20, 1);
        if(!empty($year) && !in_array($year, $year_range)){

            $this->addError($attribute,"Please select valid date");
        }
    }
```

Though it works perfectly for me, If anyone has more appropriate solution, please suggest.